# Como pegar elementos de uma página diferente?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um sistema para pegar os 4 primeiros parágrafos de uma determinada página do Wikipédia e colar-los na `div id="txtTextoResposta"` da página que o usuário está, porem o problema que estou tendo, é que não sei como fazer para pegar o conteúdo de um outro site.

Meu código:

```
function resp(){
    var input = prompt();
    var wiki = document.download("https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + input);
    var x = wiki.getElementById("mw-content-text").getElementsByTagName("p");
    var linhas = x.length > 4 ? 5 : x.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        document.getElementById("txtTextoResposta").innerHTML += x[i].innerText;
    }
}
```

Inventei a função `document.download()` para ilustrar melhor o que eu quero fazer.

Tentei também utilizando o jQuery, dessa maneira:

```
javascript: (function(e, s) {
    e.src = s;
    e.onload = function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jQuery injected');
    };
    document.head.appendChild(e);
})(document.createElement('script'), '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js')

$.get("https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + input, function(data) { $(".result").html(data); alert("Load was performed."); });
//Neste caso, o input tinha o valor "Kant"
```

Mas me retorna o seguinte erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.educacional.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Você quer fazer isso com javascript? Não pretende cachear esses resultados para não ter que rodar essa rotina de grab repetidas vezes para o mesmo termo ? Posso sugerir uma solução em PHP.

Comment: Sim, é preciso que seja feito em javascript. Pois eu não estou fazendo isso para um site, e sim para usar no console do navegador.

Comment: Mas poderia usar um ajax fazer o carregamento em backend com PHP usando o XPATH e DOM e devolver a resposta para o javascript que imprimiria no console.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se isso ajudaria, mas você poderia fazer uma requisição a url externa com jquery

$.get( "url", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
  });

[Método get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Em seguida utilizando o callback ler o conteúdo com DOM, espero que seja útil essa resposta!

Referencia para o uso de [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, veja o erro que me retorna.

Comment: É eu imaginei que daria isso o navegador bloqueou por segurança. Mas não tinha certeza. Nesse caso tanto por perfomance quanto por restrições de segurança eu aconselho o ajax para um PHP.

Comment: É, mas como eu disse, não tem como, porque eu vou usar isso no console de desenvolvedor do Google Chrome e não em um site.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação da Wikipédia, disponível em https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS:

> For anonymous requests, `origin` query string parameter can be set to `*`
>   which will allow requests from anywhere.

Para fazer requisições anônimas, é preciso usar uma query `origin=*`.

Então, funciona se a sua variável wiki estiver definida da seguinte forma:

```
var wiki = document.download("https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?origin=*&search=" + input);
```

Comment: Não funcionou, retorna o mesmo erro.